# How to set Billingaddress during sales_order_place_before programmatically

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, event-observer, sales-order, billing-address

I need `all orders` to have the `same billing address` (its because the store is used company internal) but the shipping address may vary. My thought was to set the Billing Address programmatically during `sales_order_place_before`.

Somehow the code throws me a `500 Error` every time I want to submit my `checkout`.

I have created an `Observer`, it triggers on `sales_order_place_before`, but somehow I cant get it running. I can't really find anything on this topic, I found this [Update Shipping Address Similar to Billing Address before/after placing an order using Observer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20580520/update-shipping-address-similar-to-billing-address-before-after-placing-an-order) but it doesn't work for me.

```
public function orderPlaceBefore($observer) {

    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    $billing_address = $order->getBillingAddress();
    $shippingAddress = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address')
        ->setCustomerId($billing_address->getCustomerId())
        ->setCustomerAddressId($billing_address->getCustomerAddressId())
        ->setAddressType(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address::TYPE_SHIPPING)
        ->setFirstname($billing_address->getFirstname())
        ->setMiddlename($billing_address->getMiddlename())
        ->setLastname($billing_address->getLastname())
        ->setSuffix($billing_address->getSuffix())
        ->setCompany($billing_address->getCompany())
        ->setStreet($billing_address->getStreet())
        ->setCity($billing_address->getCity())
        ->setCountry_id($billing_address->getCountryId())
        ->setRegion($billing_address->getRegion())
        ->setRegion_id($billing_address->getRegionId())
        ->setPostcode($billing_address->getPostcode())
        ->setTelephone($billing_address->getTelephone())
        ->setFax($billing_address->getFax());

    $order->setShippingAddress($shippingAddress);
```

Comment: I would really appreciate a comment on this!! :) Thank you tons in advance..